# Expected expression before token

Tags: c, traversal, depth-first-search

Here is the code I got, when trying to compile it, I get two errors which unfortunately I fail to spot at the moment, hopefully another pair of eye would point out some insights.

The error falls at these two lines

```
print_all_paths(graph, int source_id, int destination_id, visited_arr, path, path_counter);
```

Error for this one is:

```
error: expected expression before 'int'
```

Second error falls at:

```
void print_all_paths(Graph* graph, int source_id, int destination_id, int visited_arr[], int path[], int &path_counter)
```

Shows:

```
error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '&' token
```

Thank you!

Comment: You specify the types of arguments when you declare a function, not when you call it. Remove the `int`s from the call to `print_all_paths()`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Thank you the first error is no more! But any idea on the second one?...Much appreciated.

Comment: `int &path_counter` should presumably be `int * path_counter`.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths At this line `print_dfs(graph,current->v, destination_id, visited_arr, path, *path_counter);` It now says `error: too many arguments to function 'print_dfs'`, what should I do...

Comment: Your `print_dfs` function is not a part of your posted code, so we co not know about that.

Comment: @Bbz: Isn't "too many arguments to function" fairly self-explanatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare a function, you are supposed to provide all the data types of the arguments passed to the function. However, when you call the function, you do not need to specify the data types of the values passed, as they are already defined in the function header.

So change the line causing the first error to:

```
print_all_paths(graph, source_id, destination_id, visited_arr, path, path_counter); // The "int" is removed
```

The second error is caused because you cannot reference variables in C; that is **A C++** feature. Therefore, you should change `int *path_counter` instead of `int &path_counter` in the function `void print_all_paths`

Answer (score -1):

I expect you want an * instead of the &

Comment: where exactly though? You mean `path_counter`?

Comment: in `void print_all_paths` before `path_counter`